# How does JdbcPollingChannelAdapter maxRows differs from Poller maxMessagesPerPoll?

Tags: spring-integration

I have multiple `Polling` flows using the same flow logic, but varying the channel (it's a database column `id_channel` to separate rows by dependence).

On the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`, `setMaxRows` is fixed to 1. To my understandig each roundtrip to the database will fetch one row.

If I have 5 Polling flows and 10 threads, how each polling flow will "compete" with each other? Does setting `Pollers.maxMessagesPerPoll` makes any difference in the concurrency, given that `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setMaxRows` is always 1?

My `application.properties` (custom datasource) has:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10
spring.pgsql.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

Flow logic:

```
private MessageSource<Object> buildJdbcMessageSource(final int channel) {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, FETCH_QUERY);
    adapter.setMaxRows(1);
    adapter.setUpdatePerRow(true);
    adapter.setSelectSqlParameterSource(new MapSqlParameterSource(Map.of("idCanal", channel)));
    adapter.setRowMapper((RowMapper<IntControle>) (rs, i)
            -> new IntControle(rs.getLong(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3)));
    adapter.setUpdateSql(UPDATE_QUERY);

    return adapter;
}

private IntegrationFlow buildIntegrationFlow(final int channel, final long rate, final int maxMessages) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(buildJdbcMessageSource(channel),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(rate)
                                    .transactional(transactionInterceptor())
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessages)))
            .split()
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, ERROR_CHANNEL))
            .channel(SybaseFlowConfiguration.SYBASE_SINK)
            .get();
}

public IntegrationFlow pollingFlowChannel1() {
    return buildIntegrationFlow(1, properties.getChan1RateMs(), properties.getChan1MaxMessages());
}

public IntegrationFlow pollingFlowChannel2() {
    return buildIntegrationFlow(2, properties.getChan2RateMs(), properties.getChan2MaxMessages());
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some explanation in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-max-rows-versus-max-messages-per-poll.

Tell us please, if that is not enough for your expectations.

Comment: It's well explained, thanks.